# R: How to plot a line chart based on the result of two different pivot tables

Tags: r, charts, pivot-table

Please check the sample data set shown below.

In the first pivot table I need to calculate user- & month-wise late_days (All) count and in the second pivot table displaying user- & month-wise late_days where late_days= "0 or early"

Now I want to plot a line chart which represents user- & month-wise % value of 
(Total no of count where late_days= "0 or early" / Total no of count for all days).

**Example:**
Buyer **'A'** have total count for Jan 2018= 4, And for 0 or early =1 , 
Then in bar char should be displayed % value of (0 or earl/Total) = 1/4 = 25% 
Both same then 100%

In line char user vise line colour code.

```
Buyer       year_month      Late_Days

A           2018-01         0 or Early
B           2018-01         >=5
C           2018-02         >=10
A           2018-04         0 or Early
A           2018-03         >=5
B           2018-03         >=10
C           2018-05         0 or Early
A           2018-06         >=5
B           2018-07         >=10
A           2018-11         0 or Early
B           2018-11         >=5
A           2019-01         >=10
B           2019-01         0 or Early
A           2019-01         >=5
A           2019-02         >=10
```

I have created two pivot tables but I don't know how to plot a line chart based on this.

**PivotTable-1**

```
sub_data6 <- subset(inventory, Late_Days=='0 or early',
                    select=c("year_month","Late_Days","Buyer"))
rpivotTable(sub_data6,
  aggregatorName = "Count",
  rows = "Buyer",
  cols = c("year_month"),
  width = "100%",
  height = "500px")
```

**PivotTable-2**

```
sub_data5 <- subset(inventory, select=c("year_month","Late_Days","Buyer"))

rpivotTable(sub_data5,
  aggregatorName = "Count",
  rows = "Buyer",
  cols = c("year_month"),
  width = "100%",
  height = "500px")
```

Result of dput(df)

```
year_month("12-2019", "01-2020", "01-2020", "06-2018", "08-2018", "09-2018", "12-2018", "03-2019",
 "11-2016", "11-2016", "04-2019", "07-2017", "08-2017", "09-2017", "10-2017", "11-2017", "12-2017",
 "01-2018", "02-2018","03-2018", "04-2018", "05-2018", "06-2018", "07-2018", "08-2018", "09-2018",
"07-2017", "08-2017", "09-2017", "10-2017", "11-2017", "12-2017", "01-2018", "02-2018","03-2018",
 "04-2018", "05-2018", "06-2018", "07-2018", "08-2018", "09-2018","08-2017", "09-2017", "03-2018",
 "04-2019") Late_Days = c("<=20", "<=10", "<=5", "<=20", "0 or early", "0 or early", "0 or early", 
"0 or early", "0 or early", "<=30", "0 or early", "<=10", "<=5", 
"0 or early", "0 or early", "0 or early", ">30", "<=20", "<=20", 
"<=20", "<=20", ">30", "<=20", "<=5", "<=5", "<=5", "<=5", "<=10", 
"<=10", ">30", "<=5", "0 or early", "<=5", "0 or early", "0 or early", 
"0 or early", "<=10", "<=5", "0 or early", "0 or early", "0 or early"
 "<=20", "<=5", "<=5", "<=5")Buyer = c( 
"C", "D", "D", "D", "D", "A", "D", "A", "A", "C", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "C", "C", "A", "C", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "B", "B", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "C", "C", "A", "A", "A", 
)row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 
19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 20L, 31L, 
32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L)
```

**Here actually converting excel reporting to r dashboard.**
[image]

Comment: provide your `data.frame` as a `dput()` output. Will be easier to provide a solution. Just `dput(your_maindataframe_here)`

Comment: Actual Data set is too long, here actually converting excel reporting in to r dashboard. check attached screenshot.

Comment: you don't need to provide the full dataset. first 20 rows or something like that would suffice. Its alway better to provide a sample dataset from which others can work on. If data is confidential, you could provide a dummy dataset.

Comment: I update it in description please check